# javascript/jquery - countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need help with my countdown timer. i have a unix timestamp that i want to countdown from in minutes. it should just print out "X minutes left." in my span. i dont know why it isn't working. i placed the jquery above it, so jquery is in use.

HTML:

```
<span id="time-left">x</span>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var endTime = 1450992799399;
        var curTime = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        var seconds = endTime - curTime;
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds %= 60;
        $('#time-left').html() = minutes + " minutes left.";
    }, 1000);
});
```

And I want it to update every second. But right now it isn't doing anything. The text remains as "x" in my span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery uses methods, not properties, so it's

```
$(element).html('HTML to set');
```

not

```
$(element).html() = 'HTML to set';
```

Giving you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var endTime = 1450992799399;
        var curTime = Date.now();
        var seconds = curTime - endTime;
        var minutes = Math.floor((seconds / 60) / 1000);

        $('#time-left').html( minutes + " minutes left.");
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! Now it kinda works. But it shows "24159028708 minutes left.". I guess my conversion from UNIX timestamp messed up completely. lol

Comment: You don't have a unix timestamp in seconds, `1450992799399` is milliseconds, the same thing javascript returns, so stop dividing by a thousand

Comment: I'm kinda confused, I don't even know what a UNIX timestamp really is. My friend told me this (1450992799399) was a "unix timestamp" and that it is  referring to a date (today, in about 15 minutes or so). I dont need to split by 1000? It shows me some completely different number now. Im confused

Comment: So just `var curTime = new Date().getTime();` ?

Comment: And that was probably correct when your friend told you that, but those 15 minutes have past now. A unix timestamp is a moment in time, it's the number of seconds since 1. january 1970.

Comment: Awesome dude! I forgot to split by /1000 on the minutes. Thanks a bunch! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var countdown = new Date("May 28, 2018 12:00:00").getTime();
    var x = setInterval(function(){
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countdown - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor(distance % (1000 *60) / 1000);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "D " + days + " H " +  hours + " M " + minutes + " S " + seconds;
    },1000)
    if(distance < 0){
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
</script>
<div id="timer" class="timer"></div>
```